Avoid Overlay Increment in Handout Mode
I have a beamer frame where I want different behavior in handout mode than when not in handout mode. Below, when in handout mode, I am expecting two slides, a first with an item and subitem, and a second slide with a third item. When not in handout mode, I expect three slides. Instead, I get three slides in both handout and non-handout mode.
The problem seems to be the item<+- ... part. When I change it to item<.- ... in the second frame, you can see that I can get two slides in handout mode, but I now also get only two slides when not in handout mode.
In handout mode, I'd like to avoid the additional (second) slide from showing.
Here is my MWE:
\documentclass[handout]{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Test}
\begin{itemize}
    \item<+- | handout:.-> This shows up alone when not in handout mode, but should be with the subitem in handout mode
    \begin{itemize}
        \item<+- | handout:.-> This is on a second slide when not in handout mode, should be witht he first item when in handout mode
    \end{itemize}
    \item<+- | handout:+-> This is on a third slide when not in handout mode, and should still do so when in handout mode
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Test}
\begin{itemize}
    \item<+- | handout:.-> This shows up alone when not in handout mode, but should be with the subitem in handout mode
    \begin{itemize}
        \item<.- | handout:.-> This is on a second slide when not in handout mode, should be with he first item when in handout mode, and now it does once the main overlay doesn't increment the specification But now, when not in handout mode, it doesn't have it's own slide.
    \end{itemize}
    \item<+- | handout:+-> This is on a third slide when not in handout mode, and should still do so when in handout mode
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}


The easiest way to do this in my experience is to use explicit slide references in handout mode. Given that the number of slides produced per frame is typically quite small in this mode, this is generally not an especially onerous undertaking. I don't think the relative specifications such as .- can cope with handout mode, but they do just fine if you're explicit about things. So, for example,
\documentclass[handout]{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}
  
\begin{frame}{Test}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item<+- | handout:1-2> This shows up alone when not in handout mode, but should be with the subitem in handout mode
    \begin{itemize}
      \item<+- | handout:1-2> This is on a second slide when not in handout mode, should be witht he first item when in handout mode
    \end{itemize}
    \item<+- | handout:2> This is on a third slide when not in handout mode, and should still do so when in handout mode
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Test}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item<+- | handout:1-2> This shows up alone when not in handout mode, but should be with the subitem in handout mode
    \begin{itemize}
      \item<+- | handout:1-2> This is on a second slide when not in handout mode, should be with he first item when in handout mode, and now it does once the main overlay doesn't increment the specification But now, when not in handout mode, it doesn't have it's own slide.
    \end{itemize}
    \item<+- | handout:2> This is on a third slide when not in handout mode, and should still do so when in handout mode
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
  
\end{document}

[Sorry - I can't get the image right. Whatever I do the png is a png of something completely different!]

+1 for the overlays! However lmodern will work just fine in beamer. If beamer detects this package, it will automatically switch off its font replacement shenanigans (cf. beamer user guide p. 188).

Thanks for editing!

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Thanks! That is an example of something I really thought I knew. Now I have to wonder why :(.

I'm not sure when lmodern was added to the list of special cases - might have not always been there :)

An alternative approach ist to just render all slides in all modes, but filter them on the frame-level for the handout. I have found this to be way more maintainable that fiddling around with every single element:
\documentclass[handout]{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}<handout:2,3>{Test}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item<all:+-> This shows up alone when not in handout mode, but should be with the subitem in handout mode
        \begin{itemize}
            \item<all:+-> This is on a second slide when not in handout mode, should be witht he first item when in handout mode
        \end{itemize}
        \item<all:+-> This is on a third slide when not in handout mode, and should still do so when in handout mode
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}<handout:2,3>{Test}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item<all:+-> This shows up alone when not in handout mode, but should be with the subitem in handout mode
        \begin{itemize}
            \item<all:+-> This is on a second slide when not in handout mode, should be with he first item when in handout mode, and now it does once the main overlay doesn't increment the specification But now, when not in handout mode, it doesn't have it's own slide.
        \end{itemize}
        \item<all:+-> This is on a third slide when not in handout mode, and should still do so when in handout mode
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
    
\end{document}


Neat. I didn't know that would work. I can see doing this for text, especially. I wouldn't want to use it for graphics heavy stuff as I'd not want to render all the images twice. Do you know what actually it does? Does Beamer just discard the extras at shipout?

I use it especially for gfx-heavy animations to keep it maintainable  I don’t actually get the „render twice“ argument. AFAIK, beamer discards the extras before shipout, i.e. does not compile the unused stuff, but I maybe wrong here.

Another neat trick using this for developing complex animations is to go by steps of 10 in the code, but filter out at frame-level:  Something like \node<10> … \draw<20> in the code, is filtered by \frame<10,20>, so it’s just a two-stage animation. Thereby it becomes easy to later add other steps in between (e.g., a \node<15> integrated by \frame<10,15,20>) without having to change anything in the existing steps.

I'm pretty much always using some form of externalisation for images. I don't know how good those tools would be at figuring it out. And I very, very rarely use animation. It takes long enough even without.

I linked your code from GitHub, by the way, as another way in which handout mode might get used with multiple overlays per frame. memoize's author doesn't use handout mode ;).

I don’t know either. I have started to externalize manually (extra tex docs I compile to pdf from which I include the pages with \includegraphics) long before Christian Feuersänger’s tikzexternalize became available – and somehow I just stick to that approach.

There's two newer packages: memoize and robust-externalize. The external library is now unmaintained and the pgf/tikz folk advise using one of the newer options. I haven't tried robust-externalize, but I already like memoize, even though it is still getting extended/bug-fixed. But I routinely render things like fancy headings and that's not something it would be realistic to manage manually.
